# Visual Studio Setup with Salesforce CLI for M1 Mac

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode, force-cli, force, mac-os-x

Getting a below error message while using the command "Authorise and Org"

Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org

18:34:11.754 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
›   Warning: force:auth:web:login is not a sfdx command.
Did you mean auth:web:login? [y/n]:
›   Error: Run sfdx help force for a list of available commands.
18:34:17.384 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
ended with exit code 127

Answer (score 7):

The error message you got is helpful here, and tells you what to do.

There was recently ([October 22, 2020, CLI 7.77.1+, according to the release notes](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/README.md)) a change made to the CLI to reorganize some commands. `Auth` commands now live in their own top-level namespace.

The proper command is now `sfdx auth:web:login` (no longer in the "force" namespace)

Comment: extra note: for at least some time, the `sfdx force:auth:web:login` command will be aliased to the new command. No telling how long that'll be the case though.

Comment: Thanks Derek for your input :) now how should I change the command because I am using shortcut to trigger the Authorize the Org command by ctrl+shift+p and command gets trigger.

Comment: @Rohan I encourage you to read the error message and my answer again. In both places, the answer is given. Once again, `sfdx auth:web:login` is the appropriate command.